# App Crashes in inconsistent state in iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

My App crashes when I push and pop to various screens. When I type "bt" in debug area, it shows the below threads for the crash.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x257cf, 0x0278a555 libobjc.A.dylib`realizeClass(objc_class*) + 38, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x0278a555 libobjc.A.dylib`realizeClass(objc_class*) + 38
    frame #1: 0x0278a641 libobjc.A.dylib`realizeClass(objc_class*) + 274
    frame #2: 0x0278d105 libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpImpOrForward + 90
    frame #3: 0x0278d0a6 libobjc.A.dylib`_class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 55
(lldb)
```

In this project, I am using ARC. Please give suggestions regarding what could be responsible for causing these crashes. Guidance needed.

I have using below code to push the viewcontroller

```
 HowToBet *objectHowToBet=[[HowToBet alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:objectHowToBet animated:YES];
```

I think above issue may be memory issue. So any one guide me How to enable NSZombie and track this issue in xcode 5.

Thank You.

Comment: some of the object release when you push and pop to various screens pls check that.

Comment: what code did you use for navigation through screens?